What are these?
theses are swarming my truck in area southwest of meeker co

Welcome. Do you mean Meeker, CO, USA? Can you add details about when this picture was taken and provide us with some size measures (how large the insects are)?

Looks a lot like a flying ant to me. All criteria met.
